# Google cdn for jquery themes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I've found the cdn url for jquery ui js file [here](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI), but where can I found the theme css file in the cdn. I'm looking for the smoothness theme.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can find the smoothness theme from google cdn in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css.

The url is

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/< themename >/jquery-ui.css

where < themename > is the name of the theme you want.

The i18n file from cdn can be found in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't find this in the google cdn docs or jquery docs.

Answer (score 8):

For the latest version of the standard themes, you can use something like what's below (note that all but smoothness is commented out).

Excerpted from the full template, linked here, which also has templates for Microsoft and jQuery CDN:
http://www.dullsharpness.com/2011/10/30/jquery-cdn-boilerplate-starter-templates/

```
<!-- CDN COPIES OF STANDARD JQUERY THEMES (all of these are available in v1.8.16) -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you might want to use something like:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css, if you are doing the same with your CDN of the google javascript to make sure you get the most up-to-date CSS files.